# Почему цикл так работает?

Tags: java

Почему программка печатает "Значение счетчика: 5", а не печатает 5 строк:

Значение счетчика: 0
Значение счетчика: 1
Значение счетчика: 2
Значение счетчика: 3
Значение счетчика: 4

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count;

        for (count = 0; count < 5; count = count + 1);
           System.out.println("Значение счетчика: " + count);

        System.out.println("Готово! ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точка с запятой завершает выражение. `for (count = 0; count < 5; count = count + 1);` - это цикл без тела, который 5 раз ничего не делает, кроме инкремента переменной `count`. Следующая строка `System.out.println("Значение счетчика: " + count);` получается сама по себе, к циклу она не относится.

Comment: @Алексей [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).